# selenium python cannot send number as key for input

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-crawler

i tried to send phone numbers to input element below

```
<div id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.edt_mbtlTelNoCentral" class="Edit" tabindex="-1" style="left:309px;top:305px;width:85px;height:28px;" aria-label="휴대전화 가운데자리(필수입력) " aria-description="" userstatus="" status="enabled"><input id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.edt_mbtlTelNoCentral:input" class="nexainput" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:83px;height:26px;ime-mode:disabled;" value="" maxlength="4" type="text"><input id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.edt_mbtlTelNoCentral:input" class="nexainput" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:83px;height:26px;ime-mode:disabled;" value="" maxlength="4" type="text"></div>
```

with this code

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@maxlength="4"]')
actions.click(ele).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("Keys.Delete").send_keys('9049').perform()
```

but it keep send key like this
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI6vZ.png)

how can i fix this?

Comment: have you tried just sending the keys directly to the element?
`ele.send_keys("9049")`

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Yes but it didn't worked

Comment: what page are you trying to use?

Comment: @BendikKnapstadhttps://www.ehaneul.go.kr:5443/esky_p/esky_index.jsp#MENU:M211002000 here but it's korean website

Comment: sorry but the page wants me to download something. that wont happen

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Yeah that's why i didnt give the link. thank you anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am looking in the right place (my Korean is not up to scratch even with Google Translate), I believe you have two boxes matching xpath "//*[@maxlength="4"]".

I have created this example to fill both of them:

```
#get elements matching your xpath; this will return 2 items
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@maxlength="4"]')

#to fill both boxes
numbers=[1234,5678] 
for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
    elems[i].clear()
    elems[i].send_keys(num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro!